# Getting error of property name even if I defined it

Tags: angular, typescript

Getting error of property name even if I defined it

> Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'nome' of undefined

```
export class HomePage {

  inscricao = "São Bernardo";
  nome = "abc";
  nomeInvalido;

  constructor() {}
}

console.log(this.nome);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your reference to `this` is outside the scope of the class - that's why it is undefined

Answer (score 0):

The error message basically tells you everything: `this` is undefinded in the context where you use it. Either move the `console.log`-command into the class, or use an instance of the class.

```
export class HomePage {
  inscricao = "São Bernardo";
  nome = "abc";
  nomeInvalido;

  constructor() {
    console.log(this.nome)
  }
}

new Homepage()
```

or

```
export class HomePage {
  inscricao = "São Bernardo";
  nome = "abc";
  nomeInvalido;

  constructor() {}
}

console.log((new HomePage()).nome)
```

Comment: ok I was thinking maybe move inside a function? but ok thx a lot!

Comment: sure you can also use it in a function, which is declared in the `HomePage`-class